# gamma correction in opencv hog.cpp

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I dont understand the code of the gamma correction in hog.cpp in opencv, i went through some links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521003/gamma-correction-formula-gamma-or-1-gamma) which doesnt match with the code in opencv hog.cpp

```
Mat_<float> _lut(1, 256);

const float* lut = &_lut(0,0);

if( gammaCorrection )
    for( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
        _lut(0,i) = std::sqrt((float)i);
else
    for( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
        _lut(0,i) = (float)i;
```

All i understood from the code is it creates 2 dimensional array of 1x256, if gamma correction is true it will calculate the square root of data.I tried to debug going through all the files related to this code but dint understood. Can anyone briefly tell whats happening here.

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you're doing there is building a lookup table; you know the incoming data is chars, so all pixels can only have values from 0-255, so if you're doing gamma correction you precalculate the square-root. This gets used later on, inside the per-pixel gradient calculation. 
Later on in computeGradients(), you get the row pointer:

```
const uchar* imgPtr  = img.data + img.step*ymap[y];
```

Then index into the lookup table to get the pixel values for the [ -1 0 1 ] gradients:

```
        for( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {
            int x1 = xmap[x];

            dbuf[x] = (float)(lut[imgPtr[xmap[x+1]]] - lut[imgPtr[xmap[x-1]]]);
            dbuf[width + x] = (float)(lut[nextPtr[x1]] - lut[prevPtr[x1]]);
        }
```

Comment: @Sharath Please consider accepting this as the correct answer, if it solved your problem, by clicking the little check marker on the left.